# How to update an already retrieved document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm retrieving a document like this:

`user = db.users.find_one( { '_id' : ObjectId( 'anID' ) } )`

But I can't figure out how to update the document if I want to change the value of 'gender'. This doesn't work:

```
newValue = { 
        'gender' : gender
        }

db.users.update( user, newValue, False )
```

Is my syntax wrong? What's the best way to update user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your update syntax is not correct, it should be:

```
update(spec, document, upsert=False, multi=False, ...)
```

Where `spec` is the same filter that you used for the find, i.e. `{ '_id' : ObjectId( 'anID' ) }`

You can either update the document by replacing it with a modified document or use a targeted update to change only a certain value. The advantage of the targeted update is that it saves you the first round trip to the server to get the user document.

Replacement update:

```
user = db.users.find_one( { '_id' : ObjectId( 'anID' ) } )
user['gender'] = newGender
db.users.update( { '_id' : user['_id'] }, user, False)
```

Targeted update:

```
db.users.update( { '_id' : ObjectId( 'anID' ) }, \
                 { '$set': { 'gender' : newGender } }, False )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to replace the entire document you should use the [$set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) operator as:

```
db.users.update( { '_id': user['_id'] }, { '$set': newValue }, False )
```